# tightvnc is not working properly..its showing grey background with X cursor

Tags: 13.04, android, tightvncserver

i am running ubuntu suacy 13.10 over android galaxy S3 using [Linux Deploy](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy) but tightvnc not working properly....its showing grey background with X cursor ... guide me please...!!

xstartup configuration:

```
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
export XAUTHORITY
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG
echo $$ > /tmp/xsession.pid
XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE
if [ -n "`gnome-session -h | grep "\-\-session"`" ]; then
gnome-session --session=gnome
else
gnome-session
fi
```

kindly help ...!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a major bug with tightvnc and 13.10 you can read about it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tightvnc/+bug/1242879)

Comment: Thanks for reply ... yup i installed ubuntu raring 13.04 and now vncserver is working perfectly .. thanks bro :)

Comment: No problem glad to help